# After Logging in to WordPress admin , website redirecting to home page i tried all the method that i find on the web

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i am facing issue login redirection issue, on my site when ever i tried to login through wp-admin or wp-login.php with admin details. website redirects me to the home page it should be on wordpress dashboard.
"this how i do " i access to [https://www.exemple.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.www.exemple.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1"](https://www.exemple.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.www.exemple.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1%22) when i log in with admin details" redirect me to https://www.exemple.com
when i face this problem i tried to look for online solution then i find some ways but aren't working for me" exemple of thing that i did?

disable theme and plugin
remove htaccess file
change the databases to other user
install update of wordpress manual via ftp client
i add new user from database to my wordpress but is not accessing.
also i tried to upgarade php from 7.0 to 7.4 but the site goes down

Please help.

thank in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You're looking for the `login_redirect` hook filter.

- *Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/*

Our train of thought is the following: We want to make sure the `$user` is an object and is `WP_User` object (not a `WP_error` object).

We also want to check the user capabilities to determine if it is indeed an Administrator.

Upon result, we redirect.

---

### Using `WP_User::has_cap`

> While checking against a role in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results.

Head over @ https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/ to see all users default roles & capabilities.

Here I've chosen to use `update_core` which is only available to **Super-Admin** and **Administrator** roles.

You could choose a lesser capability to englobe multiple roles like `delete_posts` which would englobe **Super-Admin**, **Administrator**, and **Editor** roles. [See @ Capability vs. Role Table](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#capability-vs-role-table).

---

### Our final script

```
<?php
/**
* apply_filters
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/
* Filters the login redirect URL.
* @param String $redirect_to The redirect destination URL.
* @param String $requested_redirect_to The requested redirect destination URL passed as a parameter.
* @param Object $user WP_User object if login was successful, WP_Error object otherwise.
*/
add_filter( 'login_redirect', function ( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user ) {

  if ( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) && $user->has_cap( 'update_core' ) )

    return $redirect_to = esc_url( home_url() );

}, 10, 3 ); ?>
```

This goes in your `function.php` file.